# Sync clicks using history API with Browsersync

Tags: browser-sync, html5-history

I have a single-page application with my own JS framework using HTML5 history API. Then I'm using a apache server to serve the first page (index.php). I also have `webpack` and Browsersync.

My issue is when I want to sync clicks using the history API with Browsersync, nothing happens. I read that I have to use `connect-history-api-fallback` as middleware with Browsersync. Here is my Browsersync config:

```
new BrowserSyncPlugin({
    host : 'localhost',
        middleware : [ historyFallback() ],
        proxy: {
            target : 'http://project.local',
            middleware :[ historyFallback() ],
        }
    },{
    reload: false,
})
```

But it is doing nothing: my clicks are not synced between browsers.

Am I correctly configuring Browsersync, or does the problem come from another thing?

I may not be clear enough; don't hesitate to ask if you need more details.